# Counting last reported version in shell

Tags: bash

Struggling to write a simple tool to quickly sum up the last reported versions in a [bunch of files](http://static.dabase.com/count-stats.tar.gz). I'm using a [named pipe](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) to get the count out the loop for the final value, but the $version isn't populated which I don't understand.

```
mkfifo mypipe
for i in stats/*
do
    tail -1 $i
done | sort -n > mypipe &

while read version
do

    if test "$version" = "$last"
    then
        count=$(($count + 1))
    else
        echo $last $count
        count=1
        last=$version
    fi

done < mypipe

# $version is not printed, what's the workaroud?
echo version $version count $count
```

Perhaps people can suggest a better cleaner more suck less solution?

Comment: I don't quite understand what your script tries to accomplish, I see you're getting the last line of each file in stats, sorting them numerically and then? that second loop is weird, also notice you're comparing $last before it's assigned.

Comment: oh and use `[[` in bash instead of `test` or `[` and don't forget to quote the variables! especially when they contain filenames.

Comment: I prefer test. Square brackets are for losers. :)

Comment: `[` and `test` are identical but `[[` is an improved version, read this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Comment: @Samus_ but `[[` is not POSIX (and portable)

Comment: as I've said "use `[[` in bash" if you're writing POSIX-sh there's lots of other considerations but bash is present on all the current Linux distros so it's posrtable to some extent too.

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate problem is that the exit condition of the loop is when `read version` returns an error status. This happens when the loop reaches the end of its input file. This call to `read` also sets `version` to the empty string.

You can salvage this code by keeping the last known-good value of `version` in another variable — which you already do here, in `last`. So change the last line to `echo version $last count $count`. But there are simpler ways of doing this; [`uniq -c`, which has already been suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/7257) being the simplest, and [`awk` as a general purpose text processing tool](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/7256) being something to keep in mind as well.

While I'm at it, some general notes on shell programming.

- **Always put double quotes around variable substitutions and command substitutions**, unless you can explain why it is safe to leave them off in a particular instance. For example, `tail -1 $i` should be `tail -1 "$i"`: if you leave off the quotes, this command will fail if the file name contains whitespace or globbing characters.
- In fact, this line should be

  ```
  tail -n 1 -- "$i"
  ```

  The `--` is there in case `$i` begins with a `-`; without the `--` it would be treated as an option to `tail`. In this specific case `$i` always begins with `s` so the `--` is unnecessary, but it's a good habit to get into.
  The form `-1` is obsolete, and some modern implementations of `tail` don't support it. `-n 1` is the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/tail.html) form.
- To read a line from a file, don't use plain `read`, but `IFS= read -r`. See [How can I read line by line from a variable in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9784/how-can-i-read-line-by-line-from-a-variable-in-bash/9831#9831) Plain `read` expands backslashes (expecting a continuation line if a line ends with a `\`), and strips off leading and trailing whitespace.
- Using a named pipe requires a lot of management: you need to create it with a unique name (use `mktemp`) and make sure the permissions are correct. You may have tried and failed with the following structure:

  ```
  for i in stats/*; do … done | while read version; do … count=…; done
  echo $count
  ```

  In most shells (Bourne, ash, bash, pdksh), each component of a pipe is executed in its own subshell, so any assignment to `count` in the while loop doesn't affect the parent shell. Only in a few shells (ATT ksh, zsh) does the rightmost command in a pipeline run in the parent shell. There's a simple workaround for that: run all the code that depends on the assignments performed by a pipeline component inside that pipeline component.

  ```
  for i in stats/*; do … done | sort -n | {
    while read version; do … count=…; done;
    echo $count
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This shell works:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    test -z "$line" && continue
    version=$line # only assign version to line once we know it has a value for L23
    if test "$version" = "$last"
    then
        count=$((count + 1))
    else
        test "$last" && echo "$last $count"
        count=1
        last=$version
    fi
done < <(
for f in stats/*
do
    tail -1 "$f"
done | sort -n
)

echo $version $count
```

However it's quite slow compared to a awk line a user "mute" on #bash came up with:

`awk 'FNR==1&&NR!=1{a[latest]++}1{latest=$0}END{a[latest]++;for (v in a)printf("%5s %s\n", v, a[v]);}' stats/* | sort -n`

Answer (score 0):

From Patrick Haller off email:

```
for i in stats/*; do tail -1 $i; done | sort | uniq -c
```

Superb!